# Can you do something to a wireless mouse adapter to transform it in a wifi adapter?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mouse, wireless-adapter

Is it possible to transform a wireless mouse adapter in a wifi adapter for your pc?

Comment: What is the wireless mouse adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly not.

Most wireless chipsets are designed for one protocol or family of protocols. Even if you could get the full programming specifications for the chip in the adapter (which you probably won't) it's highly unlikely it would be flexible enough to be re-programmed for wifi.